# Number of close votes required and low traffic tags

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I don't believe the **number of close votes required** is working on low traffic and less popular tags.

- Fewer questions are read, therefore fewer close votes issued
- Less people have enough rep to close (by their 'low frequency' nature these tags don't generate much reputation for the users that follow them)
- Some people (even with enough rep) don't close questions anyway

Having said that, I can't think of a rule that can improve this situation that isn't subject to abuse. Anyone else seen this or have ideas?

**Edit:** I'm seeing this on the [Stack Overflow <kbd>sharepoint</kbd> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sharepoint). Here are examples over the last five days. Most of these have one close vote (mine):

*Belongs on Server Fault:*

- [How does a MOSS web front end route search requests to query servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310308/how-does-a-moss-web-front-end-route-search-requests-to-query-servers)
- [Cannot login to WSS 3.0 site using forms authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306592/cannot-login-to-wss-3-0-site-using-forms-authentication)
- [Verify SP2 Install for MOSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302847/verify-sp2-install-for-moss)

*Belongs on Super User:*

- [Does anyone know of any good software for SharePoint email filing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301804/does-anyone-know-of-any-good-software-for-sharepoint-email-filing)
- [Lookup field in Edit in Datasheet mode in sharepoint doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300363/lookup-field-in-edit-in-datasheet-mode-in-sharepoint-doesnt-work)

*Duplicate:*

- <strike>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289297/sharepoint-developer-pre-screening-test</strike>

**Edit 2: Is this what the <kbd>belongs-on...</kbd> tags should be used for? To alert other users with higher rep to close these questions?**

Comment: Voted to close em all.  Note, the ones you had pegged as not programming related could go to superuser.

Comment: Thanks jinguy. Maybe all it would take is people to see closures actually happening, then they might think about it.

Comment: The belongs-on-* tags shouldn't be used as a flagging device.

Comment: **Don't** use **`[belongs-on..]`** tags. Flag a moderator if you have to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If something needs to be closed, you can always rile up the clientele here on Meta or flag a mod and they'll come by and close it. Marc loves breaking out the [ban hammer](https://imgur.com/jYSSn.jpg).

Comment: Ban hammer - excellent

Comment: Darn! Can't upvote you again! I would make a feature request about upvoting edits, but I know Jeff's answer.

Comment: Hey! No fair! now, where's that "delete user" button...? ;-p

Answer (score 4):

If you think something needs to be closed, you can flag it for moderator attention. Moderators can then decide whether or not we want to listen to you. It only takes one mod vote to close anything as opposed to the 5 regular users.

I can say that once there becomes a larger userbase of 3,000+ users, it is increasingly unlikely that mods will take any action on a question unless it is blatantly necessary. The whole idea is for you guys to start policing yourselves once you hit the 3,000 reputation mark, so that we don't have to monitor every single question and close it ourselves.

Comment: Oh, so now we're going "you guys" for us peons, eh? Some moistened bint lobs a scimitar at you and this happens.

Comment: I have to say "you guys" now because my moderator controls disallow me from joining in much on the self-policing because my vote is so powerful now. I would rather that the regular users vote to close stuff than a moderator always having to come in and do it, but I recognize that this is just something that will have to happen until there are enough users to patrol the site themselves.

Comment: I'm seeing this problem on SO which already has > 3000 users. (Maybe I should edit this question to state that)

Comment: @Alex: If it's an older question on SO that isn't likely to see much traffic, go ahead and flag for a moderator.  It's the brand new questions that are only a few minutes or hours old that the community should be able to decide on without moderator intervention.  I agree with TheTXI that my one vote is too powerful to use in a lot of cases where the system is designed to let the community vote.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't feel the problem is as bad as you make it out to be, at least on SO which has been around long enough to have many, many 3k+ users.  Do you have any examples of this?  Say, a question that has been around for a few days despite being obviously in need of closing?

Even if there are such questions, if they are obvious enough, flagging for moderator attention should work.  If it's a gray area, then you're probably out of luck.  Just put your vote to close in, maybe drop a comment explaining your opinion in case other people come by later, and move on.