# Notifying OP of duplicate questions

Tags: support, questions, duplicate-questions

I'm a little confused about the correct way to notify the OP and the community of duplicate questions. The highest-voted answer in the question [How to handle duplicate questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-to-handle-duplicate-questions) and [official FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stackoverflow-work-the-official-faq) state:

> If you have edit powers add the following at the **top** of the question:
>
> > ###Duplicate of 
> > > [title of question](url to question)

However [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1383/show-possible-duplicates-in-the-main-post-before-its-closed) states (and [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5001/duplicate-possible-duplicate-question-links-displayed/5003#5003) seems to confirm) that:

> At the moment links to possible
> duplicates are inserted in the
> question text once a question is
> closed.

So does that mean if I edit the post to add the duplicate and then it is closed, the 'Duplicate' markers will be added twice? Is the FAQ out-of-date and is there a different way we should be notifying of duplicates?

Comment: The FAQ is out of date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have updated the FAQ for now, until one of the Meta Mods can verify the changes and confirm.

However the correct procedure if you can't vote to close is to leave a comment with the duplicate link and flag for moderator attention with the information. However we do normally wait for other's to vote first, unless the question is openly a duplicate, in which case it will be closed right away.

**Important**

On a site like SO where there is a significant amount of 3K+ users, please don't flag for moderator attention immediatly, just post the link. There is enough users to identify and close duplicates. On SF/SU with less users able to vote, flagging is strongly encouraged until the user base increases.

Comment: Rule of thumb would be that if the first page of users are all over 3K, that should be enough of a base to not really need to flag moderators to close.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. How long should I wait before flagging? It's rare that enough people following the `sharepoint` tag get anything closed. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16043/number-of-close-votes-required-and-low-traffic-tags

Comment: @Al - That would be a case where you would flag noting that it is a low visit flag