# Number of votes required for less popular tags

Tags: discussion, tags, migration

I use a specific example for this question but it is fairly general.

I have noticed that many questions are asked on SO about general use of Excel, tagged with [excel](/questions/tagged/excel), and/or [excel-formula](/questions/tagged/excel-formula). These questions generally don't involve any programming and belong to Super User, rather than Stack Overflow.

They sometimes get migrated to SU. However, the votes to migrate often get stuck at 3 or 4, probably because there are not so many users with enough rep following those tags. Not only do the questions not really fit the FAQ, but they would get better attention on the dedicated site.

- What is the best thing to do when that happens (apart from voting to migrate)?
- Do the posters get warned that some people have voted to migrate their questions and that it might make sense to ask them on a different site?
- Would it make sense to have the number of votes required to migrate / close etc. be related to the popularity of the tags used?

Comment: This [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16043/number-of-close-votes-required-and-low-traffic-tags) appeared in the related section (was not in the list while typing the message). It is clearly related although my question is more specifically about migration.

Answer (score 1):

> Do the posters get warned that some people have voted to migrate their questions and that it might make sense to ask them on a different site?

Who wrote the question doesn't get notified that the question has been voted to be migrated, in the same way there isn't any notification of the fact the question has been voted to be closed.
Notifying them that it is better to ask the question on a different site would have just the effect of having the same question asked in two different sites. It's not said that a question voted to be migrated is effectively migrated. It is migrated when it gets 5 votes to be migrated, or a moderator votes to migrated it, but it's not possible to know it beforehand. If the question is going to be migrated, there is no need to ask it in the suggested site, and if it is not going to be migrated, there isn't the need to ask it in the suggested site, as it on-topic where it is.

> Would it make sense to have the number of votes required to migrate / close etc. be related to the popularity of the tags used?

As far as I recall, the votes to migrate/close a question with few views expires later than a vote done on a question which has a higher number of views. (I don't remember the exact number, but votes to close start to expire when the number of views is higher than X.) This means that, for questions that are viewed few times, there is more time to vote to close it.
I am not sure I would see the number of required votes reduced; if there is effectively the need, as for questions that are definitively off-topic, a moderator can migrate the question, or close it with a single vote, and without to wait 5 users votes to close it.